# nodejs No data returning after function

Tags: node.js

I'm pretty new to nodejs and expressjs. Can someone please make sure I'm doing this right. Everytime I execute the response via the web, e.g `/names/status/10000036/` no data is being shown.

Code:

```
app.get('/names/status/:id', function(req, res) {
  var data = {
    ToonID: req.params.id
  }
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM NameApproval WHERE ToonID = ?', data.ToonID, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw (err);

      var id = rows[1];
      var wishname = rows[2];
      var result = rows[3];

      var response = {
        ToonID: id,
        WishName: wishname,
        Result: result
      };
      res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
  });
});
```

It successfully connects to the DB but it returns a simple json `{ }`

I'm using ExpressJS, mysql-node modules.

Thanks

Comment: Can you look at `data.ToonID` If it gets the correct id?

Comment: Yes it is grabbing the ID `1000036` which is the correct ID

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: previous answer was foolishly posted before I'd finished reading the question

You're taking id, wishname and result out of positions in the rows array that aren't filled.  You want to just set response to rows[0].

I'm still making assumptions about the database engine though.  You should really specify which database library you're using, and which database it's connecting to.

You also need to pass the second argument to connection.query as an array.  Here is a full correction of your code:

```
app.get('/names/status/:id', function(req, res) {
  var data = {
    ToonID: req.params.id
  }
  connection.query('SELECT id, wishname, result FROM NameApproval WHERE ToonID = ?', [data.ToonID], function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw (err);

      var id = rows[0][0];
      var wishname = rows[0][1];
      var result = rows[0][2];

      var response = {
        ToonID: id,
        WishName: wishname,
        Result: result
      };
      res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining that in a way that someone who is new to nodejs can understand, cause what you just said is so confusing sorry. :)

Comment: I just edited what DB engine I'm using in myquestion. :) and no problem.

Comment: see updated answer, it should answer all of your questions now with a code example

Comment: When using your edited code, I get a `{ }` empty JSON string

Comment: Still getting `{ }` :(

Comment: odd.  can you log out "rows" and pastebin the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `data.ToonID` option value is wrong, it should be an array:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM NameApproval WHERE ToonID = ?', [data.ToonID], function(err, rows, fields) {
```

Change `data.ToonID` with `[data.ToonID]`

As stated here: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: I did this. Still returning empty JSON string: `{ }`

Comment: Are you sure the routes are correct? It seems you are responding twice.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it. There was an issue with *arrays*. I don't know where the top *ToonID* `ToonID { }` is coming from. But thank you for everyone who helped. :)

**Output**

```
{
   ToonID: {
       ToonID: "10000036",
       WishName: "brownzilla",
       Result: "PENDING"
  }
}
```

**Code**

```
app.get('/names/status/:id', function(req, res) {
  var data = {
    ToonID: req.params.id
  }
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM NameApproval WHERE ToonID = ?', [data.ToonID], function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw (err);

      var id = rows[0]
      var wishname = rows[1]
      var result = rows[2]

      var response = {
        ToonID: id,
        WishName: wishname,
        Result: result
      };
      res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
  });
});
```